# Show more than 1 panel for Coda Slider 2.0

Tags: customization, panels, coda-slider

Is there a way to show more than 1 panel at a time with the coda slider?  I want to keep its original scrolling logic the same. The only difference, to show more than one panel at a time.  Such as 2 or 3 or 4 panels in view.

How would we go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that heads in the direction of a working example of what you'd like. I'll explain why it seems to be more trouble than it's worth (Assuming you want flexible content in both panels) and tell you how I did it.

[Here is the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/tzqYR/)

So, the initial issue is that the *current* slide is taken into account for height. Well, what if the next slide contains more content and requires a higher slider height? I suppose you'd need to compare the height of both for each height calculation. That's not so difficult, but it may lead you to more trouble if you had to fight with Niall's code.

The second issue is that you have to set a static width for two elements, which is normal in most cases for this slider, but potentially a drag depending on what your content is.

Anyhow:

```
.coda-slider-wrapper.arrows .coda-slider, .coda-slider-wrapper.arrows .coda-slider .panel { width: 230px }
.coda-slider { float: left; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 460px !important }
```

You should be able to locate these selectors using find in your editor. The `!important` is a drag, but required if you don't want to rework much code. Basically, you want to set `.coda-slider .panel` to the width you want each panel, then double the width of `.coda-slider`.

Let me know if I've missed anything here or failed to explain something properly. I'd be happy to go over this more! I've worked with this slider a lot due to inheriting a project at work that made extremely heavy use of it. I've since moved on to something custom.

Comment: thank you steve for such a rich supply of information on the slider.  Each of my panels will have the same exact width and height.  if thats the case, then the css your are presenting should be straight forward?

Comment: To be even more specific, this way you see where I'm trying to go with this, is I am trying to duplicate the same effect as this mid page slider -> that scrolls left and right and pops'up each box when you hover over it -> http://www.mgmgrand.com/

Comment: Ahhh yeah, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/UPMdc/2/. It should work well for you. The only catch is that it slides back through each panel upon reaching the end, rather than just starting the slides over once it reaches the end (Infinity sliding).

Comment: I can't thank you enough Steve - You have made my night! Thank you!